# .net - How can I store the current url on (enquire) button click then submit this on a form on the next page?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, url

I am wondering if it is possible to store the current URL of a user when they click a button div (Enquire). The button clicks to an enquiry form. SO I would like to also submit the URL with other supplied details when the form is submitted. (.aspx pages)

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath // AND STORE AS AS VARIABLE?
```

Then include in the following page form -

```
myMail.Body = "<div style='font-size:11px; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color: #333;'><h2 style='font-size:13px; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; color: #333;'>" + holTypeRBL.SelectedValue + " Enquiry</h2>"
    + "<p>Budget: " + budgetDDL.SelectedValue + "</p>"
                + "<h3>Personal Details</h3>"
                + "<p><strong>Name</strong><br />"
                + clientName + "</p>"
                + "<h3>Address Details</h3>"
                + "<p>" + getAddressDetails(country) + "</p>"
                + "<h3>Email and Phone Numbers</h3>"
                + "<p>Email: " + EmailTxtBx.Text + "<br/>"
                + "Mobile: " + checkValues(TelMobileTxtBx.Text) + "<br/>"

                + "Preferred Contact Method: " + contactPreference.SelectedItem.Text + "</p>"
                + "<h3>Trip Requirements</h3>"
                + "<p>Destination: " + holTypeRBL.SelectedValue + "<br />"
                + "Length of holiday: " + lengthTxtBx.Text + "<br />"
                + "Budget selected: " + budgetDDL.SelectedValue + "<br />"
                + "Number of adults: " + AdultsDDL.SelectedValue + "<br />"
                //+ "Number of infants (0 - 2): " + checkValues(numInfantsTxt.Text) + "<br />"
                + "Number of children (3 - 11): " + ChildrenDDL.SelectedValue + "<br />"
                //+ "Number of teenagers (12 - 18): " + checkValues(numTeenagersTxt.Text) + "<br />"
                + "Date of departure: " + date.Text + "</p>"
                + "<h3>Hotels</h3>"
                + getHotelInfo()
                + "<h3>Flight Requirements</h3>"
                + "<p>Require flights: " + requireFlightsRBL.SelectedValue + "<br />"

                + "Provide quote for Premium Economy class: " + checkFlightClass(premiumEconomyChkbx.Checked) + "<br />"
                + "Provide quote for Business class: " + checkFlightClass(businessClassChkbx.Checked) + "</p>"
                + "<p><strong>Special Requirements</strong><br />"
                + specialTxtArea.Value + "</p>"
                + "<p><!-- <strong>Located via: " + SourceDDL.getSelectedSource() + "</strong>--></p></div>"
                + "Located Via: " + Source2DDL.SelectedValue + "<br />"
                + "If Other: " + othersourceTxtBx.Text + "<br/>"
                + "<p><strong>Golf Club Member " + golfclubTxtBx.Text + "</strong></p></div>";
```

Comment: You can store it either in the Viewstate or Session.

Comment: Thank you, I'm googleing viewstate as we speak :) I'll try a test with it. Viewstate is for the same page, so I need to use Session I guess to use the users URL on a different .aspx page.